# How to reduce gap when applying css page break properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a large table with hundreds of rows. Now when i am trying to print this in google chrome then column overflow without header. So i am creating few jquery and css style to avoid this.. it working good but page break taking huge gaps between two page.. how to avoid this problem.. here is my code

```
<style>
@media print { .not-display{ display: inline-grid; } .page-break{ display: block; page-break-after: always;  }  } 
@media screen{ .not-display{ display: none; } } 
</style>

<table class="table table-condensed" id="myTable">
<tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>
<!--- hundreds of rows----->
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length; 
var i;
for(i=20;i<rowCount;i=i+20){
$("#myTable tr:nth-child("+i+")").after('<tr class="page-break">
<td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="not-display">
<td>Account Code</td>
<td>Head Of Account</td>    
<td>Opening Debit Balance</td></tr>');  
}
});
</script>
```

Here is my screen shot

[image]

Comment: pls share some fiddle code.

Comment: Have you checked in the console to see which element contains the space?

Comment: I believe it's to do with the fact that tables are not true block level elements.  I have tried the exact code below (plus your CSS above) and changed all table elements to divs - and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but it will solve a different problem.  In your current code, the `for loop` will count the inserted `<tr>`, so it will get out of sync, and also the total number of rows will be greater than `rowCount` which is determined at the start.  Maybe try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
  $('<tr class="page-break"><td colspan="3"></td></tr><tr class="not-display"><td>Account Code</td><td>Head Of Account</td><td>Opening Debit Balance</td></tr>').insertBefore($("#myTable tr:nth-child(21n)"));  
});
```

That just inserts your page break code before every 20th row without looping through.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/som16p7a/)

Comment: I found the best solution was to end the table, and start a new one. Returning the control of page breaks to natural block elements.
Depending on browser (and browser version on chrome), you get VERY different results with this gapping issue. 
I haven't found a solution, other than as mentioned -- just skipping the entire table page break idea.